# Lazy-loading dynamically displayed images?

Tags: javascript, php, lazy-loading

I'm displaying images from my database using a `while` loop and I've been trying to find a way to to lazy-load those dynamically displayed images.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy");    
  var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;

  function lazyload () {
    if(lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
    }    

    lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
        lazyloadImages.forEach(function(img) {
            if(img.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop)) {
              img.src = img.dataset.src;
              img.classList.remove('lazy');
            }
        });
        if(lazyloadImages.length == 0) { 
          document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
          window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
          window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
        }
    }, 20);
  }

  document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
  window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
  window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
});
```

I always face the same issue: the images won't load until I start scrolling. This means the first images should be displayed normally (i.e. without lazy-load), but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this as they're all displayed by the same loop.

I've been searching for something but all tutorials/scripts display the content once the visitor starts scrolling.

Is there any tutorial (or script) out there on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe add `document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);` for adding listener on document load?

Answer (score 0):

You can place something like a flag to make some images to be initially loaded in the data-* attribute. Hence, place the attribute to your image like this,

```
<img data-initial="true" >
```

Then, add this code to ready function to make them initially loaded

```
lazyloadImages.forEach(function(img){
 if($(img).data('initial')){
  img.src = img.dataset.src;
  img.classList.remove('lazy');
 }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work cause I can't place the data-initial attribute to some specific images as all my images are displayed by the same `while` loop